# Rails get related items through two different relationships

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a "two middleman" model setup as shown below:

```
User
  has_many :comments
  has_many :ratings

Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie

Rating
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie

Movie
  has_many :comments
  has_many :ratings
```

**Whats the best way to get all `Movies` that a `User` is associated with (either commented on or rated)?**

I'd like to be able to call `User.get_movies(user_id)` and get back an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so that it's chainable (i.e. `User.get_movies(user_id).limit(3).order(...)`). This returns a regular old array, and I suspect I'm hitting the database way more than I need to be.

```
def self.get_movies(user_id)
  user = self.where(:id => user_id).includes({:comments => :movie}, {:ratings => :movie})
  movies = []
  user.comments.each do |comment|
    movies.push(comment.movie)
  end
  user.ratings.each do |rating|
    movies.push(rating.movie)
  end
  movies.uniq!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def movies
  Movie.includes(:ratings, :comments).where("`ratings`.user_id = ? OR `comments`.user_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

Untested, but I'm pretty sure using a `joins` instead of `includes` also works.

Comment: interesting... feels a little hacky though setting up those extra relationships

Comment: I almost need something like `has_many :movies, :through => [:comments, :ratings]` - but I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist

Comment: @brittohalloran: can you try the second option?

Comment: Yeah I tried messing around with joins before too - your code return only `Movies` which have **both** a comment and rating from that user

Comment: I can just do it twice and push the arrays together and filter uniques, but thats about as good as I had it before

Comment: GOT IT - replace the `.joins(...).joins(...)` with `.includes(:ratings, :comments)` and it works perfect. Returns a relation and doesn't include duplicates. Fix it and I'll mark as the answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: using includes() is 3 db hits, not much different than making the queries yourself.

Comment: theres no way to avoid those hits - you need the relationship data that is only stored in the comments and ratings tables

Comment: wouldn't a `.joins(:ratings, :comments)` work the same with less DB hits?